# Windows Phone 7 Physical Button Overloading

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Is it possible to get access to any of the events raised by the phone's physical buttons? Specifically the volume buttons. A push in any direction would be great with this.

Comment: Hopefully not since this is a bad user experience. The behavior of those buttons should be predictable

Comment: It is bad if you modify the sound level, but I think reading the current volume is absolutely fine. For example your application could show different visuals depending on the sound level.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Only the Back button, and even then your ability to do things is severely limited.  Modifying the behavior of any of these buttons (outside of the allowed modifications to the Back button) will cause your app to be rejected from certification.

Here is what the WP7 [UI Design and Interaction Guidelines](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=183218) say:

- "Developers **do not** have access to modify the **Start button** behavior..." pg. 107
- "Developers **cannot** modify or change the behavior of the **Search Button**." pg. 109
- "Developers should only implement **Back Button** behaviors that navigate back or dismiss context menus or modal dialog boxes. All other implementations are prohibited." p. 111
- "Developers **do not** have access to modify the **Power button** behavior..." pg. 113
- "Developers **cannot** edit the **audio transport controls** overlay or override the **Volume Buttons** behaviors." pg. 115
- "Developers **cannot** modify or change the behavior of the **Camera Button**." pg. 117