# How to check whenever the volume button was pressed and override the function?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to make a application which should run in background and I need to know when is the volume button(-) pressed .

If it was pressed then I need to execute the back function (   `NavigationService.GoBack();` )

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: This was answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997632/windows-phone-7-physical-button-overloading

Answer (score 0):

Developers cannot edit the audio transport controls overlay or override the Volume Buttons behaviors.

Comment: Well, in this case how can I know if the volume button was pressed?

Comment: You can't. UI Design and Interaction Guidelines : http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=183218