# using mobile keyboard search button

Tags: windows-phone-8, soft-keyboard

I have a search textbox in my windows phone 8 app. I dont want to add a search button for this, but rather use the search button on the mobile soft keyboard.
Any code snippets or links providing inputs for the same?.
Also I might deploy this app on android and iOS, so will the logic work for that too, as used for windows phone using c#?.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible, and if you customize the buttons in a way that could be considered not too consistent for user experience, it may not be accepted for certification.

Take a look at this already existing SO post :

[Windows Phone 7 Physical Button Overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997632/windows-phone-7-physical-button-overloading)

Answer (score 0):

You could instead use the "enter key" in your keyboard and that way eliminate the extra icon.

I can supply code sample.

**Edit**

```
    If (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    { 
       // do search stuff here
    }
```

This should be put inside the event for textchanged.
Then It would work.

Hope it helped

Comment: So is enter equivalent to search?. Like I currently have an android phone, and whenever I click on search text box, the soft keyboard has search instead of an enter. So implementing for enter key would work here?.

Comment: Yes.
If you have a textbox, a user inputs whatever. You can then set the enter-key from the mobile keyboard to call the function you want for searching. Then for some nice elements you should also upon this event change the textbox to readonly, so removing interaction. And then show some animation, maybe progressbar you can find in the toolbox or by starting to write it in xaml.

Comment: You can add Inputscope="Search" in the xaml declaring the text box. This will give you the search style keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

In the keydown eventhandler use

```
If (e.Key == Key.Enter)
{ 
   // do search stuff here
}
```